# How can i reverse only one axis of a quaternion?

Tags: unity-game-engine, axis, quaternions

I created two objects in Unity3D, representing an upperarm (parent) and a lowerarm (child), joined with a character joint. The rotation of these objects is driven by 2 quaternions which i gather from an IMU located on the upperarm and lowerarm. I calibrate both quaternions. My objective is to visualize an elbow flexion/extension.

Q in the name indicates it is a Quaternion. QImu indicates it is the Quaternion from the IMU. Qstart indicates it is the initial starting orientation of the IMU.

```
// upperarm script attached to upperarm object
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            QstartUpperArm = QimuUpperArm;
        }

        transform.localRotation = QstartUpperArm * Quaternion.Inverse(QimuUpperArm);
```

```
// lowerarm script attached to lowerarm object
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            QstartLowerArm = QimuLowerArm;
        }

        QimuLowerArm = QstartLowerArm * Quaternion.Inverse(QimuLowerArm);
transform.localrotation = Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qimu1new;
```

The Upperarm object is rotating exactly as expected. The lowerarm object however has one the y-axis reversed. All other axis are fine. How can i change the sign of this one axis using the Quaternion?

Comment: Rotate about a perpendicular axis by 180 degrees.   Unfortunately you can't negate just one axis without using negative scale or changing the handedness of the whole system.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "the y-axis is reversed"? Are you saying it's rotating the wrong direction around the upper arm's local y axis? We might need images or a video to get a visual of what's happening here.

Comment: This is kind of a shot in the dark without seeing exactly what's going on... Try this: `Quaternion reversedY = Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qimu1new;` `transform.localrotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.Scale(reversedY, new Vector3(1f, -1f, 1f) ) );`

Comment: @pvand let us know if that works

Comment: I found something online which had a similar issue, the solution is:
```Vector3 myEulerAngles = QimuLowerArm.eulerAngles;
Quaternion invertedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(myEulerAngles.x, -myEulerAngles.y, myEulerAngles.z);
       
        transform.localRotation = invertedRotation;
```
So i guess your soluiton is kind of similar.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do this directly in a `Quaternion`. It sounds like you are confusing `Quaternion` (which has 4 components `x,y,z,w`) with the Euler space representation in `x,y,z`.

You could try using something like

```
var invertedRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.Scale(QimuLowerArm.eulerAngles, Vector3.up * -1));
```

Depending on which is the rotation you have to invert (didn't clearly see this in your code).

- [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) returns an Euler representation of the `Quaternion`
- [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html) multiplies to `Vector3` component wise. In this case by `Vector3.up * -1 == new Vector3(0, -1, 0);`
- [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) generates a `Quaternion` for a rotation on given Euler angles. One has to note here that the rotations are applied in the order `x` then `z` then `y` but since you are inverting the latter it should be fine.

---

An alternative afaik (not so sure about) is to

- negate the according axis component
- negate the `w` component

I still wouldn't do this directly in the quaternion because the order matters a lot but do e.g.

```
var invertedRotation = new Quaternion (QimuLowerArm.x, - QimuLowerArm.y, QimuLowerArm.z, -QimuLowerArm.w);
```

Comment: The first solution kind of works, whenever i hold the upperarm in the same rotation. However if i start to rotate the upperarm, the lowerarm start to rotate over the axis i just reversed. In other words i start to flex when i rotate my upperarm-object sideways...